# Copying from Windows to Linux without copying the entire path

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, cygwin, scp

I am using Cygwin to copy all the files in a local windows folder to an EC2 linux instance inside of powershell.  When I attempt to copy all the files in a folder, it copies the pathname as a folder:

```
\cygwin64\bin\scp.exe -i "C:\cygwin64\home\Ken\ken-key-pair.pem" -vr \git\configs\configs_test\ ec2-user@ec2-22-75-189-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/temp4configs/
```

will copy the correct files, but incorrectly include the path in a Windows format a path like:

/var/www/html/temp4configs/\git\configs\configs_test/file.php

I have tried an asterisk after the folder without the -r, such as:

```
\cygwin64\bin\scp.exe -i "C:\cygwin64\home\Ken\ken-key-pair.pem" -v \git\configs\configs_test\* ec2-user@ec2-22-75-189-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/temp4configs/
```

but that will return an error such as

"gitconfigsconfigs_test*: No such file or directory"

What can I do to copy the files without copying the path?

Thanks

Comment: If is cygwin scp, why are you not using POSIX PATH  `scp.exe -i "/home/Ken/ken-key-pair.pem" -vr /git/configs/configs_test/` ?

Comment: it will return no such file or directory
/git/configs/configs_test: No such file or directory

Comment: If the directory is  `C:\git\configs\configs_test\ ` as windows path, you should use   `/cygdrive/c/git/configs/configs_test/` as Cygwin path

Comment: That is it!  Thanks a ton, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using cygwin programs is safer to use POSIX Path, and most of the time is the only way. To covert from windows to posix PATH use `cygpath`

```
$ cygpath -u "C:\cygwin64\home\Ken\ken-key-pair.pem"
/home/Ken/ken-key-pair.pem

$ cygpath -u "C:\git\configs\configs_test\ "
/cygdrive/c/git/configs/configs_test/
```

Using the windows one, will cause the server to misunderstand the client request